# How do i add search functionality in gridview in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview, filter

My android app consists of a gridview with an image and a text below it. I am passing a array of strings into the textview. I want the edittext field to act as a search bar and filter the results.I have seen other questions relating this but they seem to filter an arraylist which is passed into a Listview. How do i filter an array of strings in a gridview?

I know i should add a a TextWatcher to listen for text changes on the EditText but after that how do i filter my data?

Here is my code

**Mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText inputSearch;
GridView grid;

public static String[] Sname = {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, Sname);
    grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " + Sname[+position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


    }
}
```

CustomGrid.java

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private final String[] Sname;


public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] Sname) {
    mContext = c;

    this.Sname = Sname;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Sname.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        textView.setText(Sname[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.image1);

    return grid; }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your adapter ie `CustomGrid` a `filter(String)` method.
You also add a field `String [] toDisplay` in your adapter.

In your constructor you add `toDisplay = Sname` and in all your other methos you replace `Sname`by `toDisplay`

In the `filter` method create a new string array with only the string from `Sname` that match the desired string. Set this new array to `toDisplay`.

Then call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method on your `CustomGrid`

Example of filtering method :

```
public void filter(String toMatch) {
     List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (String string : Sname) {
         if (string.matches(toMatch)) {//on whatever mathcing you feel to use
               matches.add(string);
          }
      }
      toDisplay = new String[matches.size()];
      toDisplay = matches.toArray(toDisplay);

     notifyDataSetChanged(); //update your grid view
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to create a filter method?

Comment: Since arrays have a defined size.

Comment: I edit my answer to provide you an example of filtering method